# Mouse Listern on multiple JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have created some dynamical `JLabels` and i have added `MouseLister` to each of them. Now the problem is how can i detect which `JLabel` I have Clicked?
Here's my code.

```
    int c1=40;
    setLayout(null);
    jPanel1.setSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 10));
        JLabel[] jl = new JLabel[c1];
    for(int i=c1-1; i>=0; i--){
        jl[i] = new JLabel();
        //jl.setText("O");
        jl[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        jl[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(NewJFrame.class.getResource("booked.png")));
        jl[i].setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jPanel1.add(jl[i]);
        jl[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){

            }
    });
    }
```

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). Layouts can be added to, 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Consider using multiple `JButton` components with an `ActionListener` instead of the label/mouse listener combo.  This is better for the user, since they can use mouse **or** keyboard to operate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for each JLabel you are adding a new/seperate MouseAdapter Object

```
 jl[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){

        }
});
```

So calling me.getComponent() inside the mousePressed event should return you the Label Object

```
jl[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
                   //Better to check if its returning JLabel obejct using instance of
                   JLabel c = (JLabel) me.getComponent();
            }
    });
```

Comment: But how can i uniquely identify that JLabel ? @Sarfaraz Khan

Comment: OK i got the solution i added name for each JLabel and using your me.getComponent().getName() i can identify each JLabel. Thanks for the help.